# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/pac4j/core/http/HttpActionAdapter

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-injection

I am facing **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/pac4j/core/http/HttpActionAdapter** while I am pretty sure I included the **pac4j-core** jar.
these are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.beust:jcommander:1.48'
    implementation 'io.buji:buji-pac4j:2.9.0'
    implementation 'org.pac4j:pac4j-oauth:3.6.1'
    implementation 'org.pac4j:pac4j-cas:3.6.1'
    implementation 'org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-api:3.3.0'
    implementation 'org.pac4j:pac4j-saml:3.9.0'
    implementation 'org.pac4j:pac4j-ldap:3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
    implementation "org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.4.1"
    implementation "org.apache.shiro:shiro-web:1.4.1"
    implementation "org.apache.shiro:shiro-guice:1.4.1"
    
    implementation  "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.36"
    implementation "org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.36"
    implementation "org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.36"
    implementation "org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.36"
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.3.0-alpha14'
    implementation 'commons-cli:commons-cli:1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.inject:guice:4.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.inject.extensions:guice-servlet:4.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.inject.extensions:guice-persist:4.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.inject.extensions:guice-multibindings:4.2.2'
    implementation 'org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:3.15.1.Final'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:8.5.13'
    
    
    implementation "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0"
    implementation "javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:2.3.1"
    implementation 'javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final'
    
    implementation 'org.eclipse.birt.runtime:org.eclipse.birt.runtime:4.5.0a'
    
    implementation 'org.pac4j:pac4j-http:3.8.3'
    implementation 'org.pac4j:pac4j-oidc:3.8.3'
    implementation 'org.pac4j:pac4j-core:3.8.3'

}
```

this line is throwing error **Guice.createInjector(new AppServletModule());**
and these are the imports in **AppServletModule.java**:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.google.inject.Module;
import com.google.inject.matcher.AbstractMatcher;
import com.google.inject.matcher.Matchers;
import com.google.inject.persist.PersistFilter;
import com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule;
import com.tobris.app.AppModule;
import com.tobris.app.AppSettings;
import com.tobris.app.internal.AppFilter;
import com.tobris.auth.AuthModule;
import com.tobris.db.JpaModule;
import com.tobris.db.tenants.PostSessionTenantFilter;
import com.tobris.db.tenants.PreSessionTenantFilter;
import com.tobris.meta.MetaScanner;
import com.tobris.quartz.SchedulerModule;
import com.tobris.rpc.ObjectMapperProvider;
import com.tobris.rpc.Request;
import com.tobris.rpc.RequestFilter;
import com.tobris.rpc.Response;
import com.tobris.rpc.ResponseInterceptor;
import com.tobris.web.servlet.CorsFilter;
import com.tobris.web.servlet.I18nServlet;
import com.tobris.web.servlet.NoCacheFilter;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import org.apache.shiro.guice.web.GuiceShiroFilter;
```

Answer (score 0):

**com.github.ruediste.salta:salta-guice** was a missing dependency